# Select and Update in the same time?

Tags: sql, multithreading, ms-access

I'm a beginner and learning how to do multithreading in `Python`. `SQL` query is needed (I'm not ready to dive into complicated `SQL` stuff right now). I'm using `MS Access` as a database.

There is three fields in the table: `ComputerName`, `isPing`, `inProgress`. Needed SQL query to SELECT one of the `ComputerName` that are currently not `inProgress` and marked it as `inProgress` and **in the same time** as it SELECTed.

```
SELECT TOP 1
  Table1.ComputerName,
  Table1.isPing,
  Table1.inProgress
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.inProgress) = FALSE));

UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.inProgress = TRUE
WHERE (((Table1.ComputerName) = [Enter computer name:]));
```

Comment: You can't do a select and an update in the same statement.  Typically, this problem is handled using a stored procedure or a transaction, both of which can do a select/update (update/select?) atomically.

Comment: @tim-biegeleisen how would advise to approach the issue? Potentially I would like to be able to run my program on several computers to speed up the process of pinging

Comment: Edit your question and include the select and update statements.  Maybe we can combine both into a single update.

Comment: @Tim done :) Please have a look

Comment: Logically, you only need your UPDATE statement.

Comment: @Rene UPDATE statement doesn't return anything except a number of affected rows, does it? Example of how to provide a thread with a computer name to work on are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be possible to use `TOP` in a subquery with Access in a `WHERE` clause.  If so, then you can try using the following `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET inProgress = True
WHERE ComputerName = (SELECT TOP 1 ComputerName FROM Table1 WHERE inProgress = False)
```

Note that using using `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` clause does not make much sense, because you are providing no logic with regard to *which* of the matching records should be chosen first.  You probably would want to add `ORDER BY` to the above subquery.  Also note that, as I mentioned in the comments, it is not possible to update and select at the same time.  If you really need the fields from your original `SELECT`, then you would need a separate query/statement for that.  One option might to label the updates with a timestamp, and then select the most recently updated record after the fact.

Comment: Top 1 is needed is a sense of a particular thread will be working on a particular ComputerName. A single thread needs a single ComputerName. A thread doesn't know on which computer names other threads are working. This update query doesn't provide such computer name for a thread to work on?